# Magento AW-Blog: Different Template for Post View

Tags: xml, templates, magento, blogs

We're using Magento 1.7.0.2 and the modification "Aw-Blog" in the latest version.
Is it possible to give the blog_post_view a different Template?

We need to open the post.phtml site in a lightbox with iframe/ajax loading.
Therefore I need to disable everything but just the content section of the Post View.

That is what we already tried:

```
<blog_post_view translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/post.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </blog_post_view>
```

in the aw_blog.xml we tried to set the template "popup.phtml" to the root.
Somehow this hasn't worked and that's confusing us because this method works fine already in our modified "sendtofriend" file... we did the same thing there, loading the send to friend form in a iframe lightbox.

Are we doing something wrong?
Can someone help us? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably not a aw blog case but just a mistake from us. Maybe we have set the SetTemplate wrong or we have chosen the wrong tags. Help is really really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in the Blog config in the backend at system/config/blog (aheadworks menu in left column). There you will find the page layout is set to 2columns-right.

To change the layout to the popup you will need to add an extra template to Magento's layout's.

Magento give's an example of how to do this by [following this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates).

Tutsplus has a more [complete description here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419). But you will have to scroll down to where is says **"Creating Custom Module Layout and Block Files"**

When you are done following the tutorial you will be able to select the popup template in the system/config/blog

Cheerz!

Answer (score -1):

In order for xml to work I needed to set:

```
//PostController()

public function viewAction() {<br />
        $this->loadLayout();<br />
        $this->renderLayout();

//... 
}
```

inside the `PostController()` view action. It then started to render my layout.

Hope it helps,